# Relearning basic technique after 10 years of playing drums

Tags: technique, drums

I started playing drums when I was nine, and mostly stopped when I moved to another city when I was 19, and have been practicing maybe once a month or two for the past few years. I used to be really good and am definitely nowhere near where I used to be (but haven't forgotten everything)

I started practicing more a few months back and have been having lessons - but my drum teacher has noticed that my technique was pretty bad. For example, I didn't know what an upstroke/downstroke/etc was!

My drum lessons have basically consisted of learning basic technique from scratch, and I'm finding it super boring and frustrating. Am I right to be frustrated or should I power through it? Is it that important considering I managed for years without it?

Comment: I'd combine two things. Carrying on trying to get back to how you were, playing stuff you played then, but also listening to teacher, and taking on board everything suggested. Between the two, you'll come up with compromises - which may, or may not suit teacher. Then's the time for heart-to-heart discussion. At the same time, learn to read. There are precious few drummers out there who read well, so opportunities will be greater should you decide to get more serious.

Comment: That's kind of what I've been doing, but to be honest I haven't been getting the balance exactly right! Drums aren't my only instrument and I was in various big bands / brass bands for years so I can read well :)

Answer (score 1):

If you managed to read and play drum parts in big bands, successfully, ten years and more ago, what prompted you to take on a teacher? All the guys I play with in good big bands are good players - there's hardly any room for otherwise.

So, you must have reached a fair level, thus the question. What did /do you feel you're lacking? With this information, you may attract an answer or two, sadly lacking at present. Maybe my comment ought to be included within this 'answer'.